# Kibana query for conditions on multiple events/documents on the same key field

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I'm running on ES 7.x and my data in an index where the same CustID is on multiple events/document with different field values, example:
[Sample data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vNnTX.jpg)

I need to query for customers with CustomerType 1 and with Action includes "Search", "AddToCart" and "Submit" (these actions are on diff events with diff timestamps), and the result would be the CustomerID "111".
How do I construct such a query in Kibana visualize (linechart, table, etc.)?
Thank you!

Comment: In other words, it would be the union of the following individual queries on the CUSTOMERID field:

CUSTOMERTYPE:1, ACTION:"Search", ACTION:"AddToCart", ACTION:"Submit"

Comment: If I understand well, you want to find all `CustomerId` that are `CustomerType:1` and generated the event `Search` `AddToCart` and `Submit` ?

Does the temporal order matter ?

Comment: @Paulo that is correct. So if I search for all CustomerType 1 who performed the action Search and the AddToCart then Submit (these actions came in diff events with diff timestamps for the same customer id), then the result would be customer ID "111". I want to use Kibana visualize to show a graph of this, but not sure if that's possible. Sounds like using the Union query. Thx.

Comment: @Paulo the temporal order does not matter, bc we know the action Search will come before AddToCart then before Submit.

Comment: Okay, I was about to suggest you look into EQL https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/eql.html but if you found a solution, awesome. don't forget to share it :D